# datepicker showing another place in IE8

Tags: php, jquery

I am using j-query date-picker. Its fine in Firefox & Chrome but not in IE 8. date-picker box showing another place on browser in IE 8. I want to display date-picker near date text-box. So Please suggest.

I am adding file -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
```

PHP code is -

```
    <?php

for($i=0;$i<$sibling_number;$i++)
{
?>
$(function() {
 $('#fromdate_<?php echo $i;?>').datepick();
});
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please show your html and jquery code?

Comment: show us your css and html code

Comment: check on fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NUf8n/

Comment: date-picker showing fine in Firefox & Chrome but date-picker is not showing proper place in IE 8